# Android: How can we move a playing video from an activity to another activity or dialog without re-buffering?

Tags: android, video, popup

Can we move a playing video from an activity to a popup dialog without disturbing the play?

I have tried it, but failed to manage to get it work with the SurfaceView as its creating a hole in the popup and is displaying the content in the Activity behind.

Alternately, tried removing the video (either being played in SurfaceView / VideoView) from activity and added to a dialog. But, this re-buffers the video and I want to play continuously without a re-buffer.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you can see this link for that if any prob then ask me be friendly

I have not tried it myself to say for certain, but I think if you put a VideoView as the argument into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#addContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) it should be what you're after. Just make the alert be brought up on the button's listener. It's http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html that you want to send in an instance of.

Comment: Able to play the video in popup. But, my problem is a bit weird. I need to play the video continuously even while switching, without re-buffering it again and again while moving the player from the activity to the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Set below theme to android mainfiest of class file which have videoview or surface view.

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

try this it may help you.

Comment: This does not work in my case. All I want to do is play video continuously even while switching between interfaces.